# Auto adding row to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, custom-controls

I'm programming in WPF(c#). I want a data grid that can automatically add new row to itself as you see in Sql-server :

[image]

please look at the last row in the picture. In this control if you want to add new row you must fill three columns then a new row will be added automatically. How can I make some control like this with or without DataGrid? any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is built in to the `DataGrid` control, just set `CanUserAddRows` to true

```
  <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" />
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far i know it is doable, but hard. I also had to make something like this, but what i did in the end is just making a new form with textboxes and then inserting in the database. And offcourse a method when the form js closed it refreshed the datagrid.

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid already have a property for that.

```
 CanUserAddRows="True"
```